# Why bazel remote cache hit is greater than total actions number

Tags: bazel

We are using Bazel to build and test with remote cache. And when running `bazel test`, sometimes Bazel reports that the remote cache hits number is greater than the total actions number. In which cases can this happen? I just assume that the remote cache hit should always less than the total actions.

The Bazel version we are using is 3.7.0

Answer (score 0):

[Bazel documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/remote-caching-debug.html) suggests:

> If you are getting 0 processes (or a number lower than expected), run bazel clean followed by your build/test command.

Maybe for some reason your cache is "damaged".

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

We copy the bazel local build artifacts from a clean build and use this as local cache to speed up the build/test time. And at the same time we are using remote cache. Can this influence the actions and hit numbers?